# Passing files in POST using Requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting the below error when making a requests call post method

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'files'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

I tried

```
response = requests.post("url",headers={mytoken},params=p,files=files)

files = { "file 1": open("sample.pdf",'rb'), "file 2":open("sample11.pdf",'rb')}
```

I want to get 200 status but I'm getting 422 validation error. Any idea why? It's for API Testing purposes, Im new to this I've been debugging this for the whole day but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What type of payload are you passing the request? Try changing `params=` to `data=` or `json=` in your requests if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question what kind of a request the server is expecting. Also, its not clear the exact code snippet you are using too.
From the question, the snippet looks like as follows,

```
response = requests.post("url",headers={mytoken},params=p,files=files)

files = { "file 1": open("sample.pdf",'rb'), "file 2":open("sample11.pdf",'rb')}
```

if so, that means you are reading files after you send the request, may be thats why the server complained about missing `files` field.

See the below example on how you can send two files to an endpoint expecting files.

```
import requests
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

post_url = "https://exampledomain.local/upload"

file1 = open("sample1.pdf", "rb")
file2 = open("sample2.pdf", "rb")

files = {"file1": file1, "file2": file2}

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer <your_token_here>"}

params = {"file_type": "pdf"}

response = requests.post(post_url, files=files, headers=headers, params=params)

file1.close()
file2.close()

logger.debug(response.text)
```